# How to parse JSON with keys from a BASH variable using jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON array in this format

```
{
  "id": 707860,
  "name": "Hurzuf",
  "country": "UA",
  "coord": {
    "lon": 34.283333,
    "lat": 44.549999
  }
}
```

I am using `jq` to parse it. I'm trying to extract the values of only the keys which are provided in a BASH variable. I tried this with one key in the variable and it works.

```
KEY=id
jq -r --arg key $KEY '.[] | .[$key]'
```

However when I tried the same with `KEY=coord.lat` the output is `null` and I'm stumped when the number of keys isn't a given.

For example, if the variable is

```
KEYS=id,name
```

then the output should be

```
707860,"Hurzuf"
```

or, if the variable is

```
KEYS=coord.lon,coord.lat
```

then the output should be

```
 34.283333,44.549999
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split `$key` into individual paths and convert each to a format `getpath` could understand. Then you can collect values they point to in an array and join them by commas.

For example, if it's guaranteed that no single path component contain a dot character, something like this should work fine:

```
[getpath(($key / ",")[] / ".")] | join(",")
```

```
$ KEYS=id,coord.lon,coord.lat
$ jq -r '[getpath(($key / ",")[] / ".")] | join(",")' file --arg key "$KEYS"
707860,34.283333,44.549999
```

Comment: @exonyz Then your input is an array. `jq -r '.[] | [getpath`... will work